# How to place textarea next to logo?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, position, textarea

Here is a minor [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gsamaras/6me33s8y/4) of my code. As you can see the textarea is too far from the logo. I would like it to be next to the logo (when on desktop) and below the logo (when on mobile).

The CSS of the textarea:

```
textarea{  
  display:block !important;
  box-sizing: padding-box !important;
  overflow:hidden !important;    
  padding:10px !important;
  width:250px !important;
  font-size:14px !important;
  border-radius:8px !important;
  border:6px solid #556677 !important;
}
```

Comment: @mark.hch there was a problem with the fiddle, is it OK now?

Comment: Are you open to using a flexbox for a complete solution?

Comment: I have no idea what's that @Michael_B. If it works (i.e.the expand works and it's pretty) then of course!

Comment: Flexbox is a CSS3 module for layouts. Very efficient and minimal code. Supported by all major browsers, except IE 8 & 9. If you don't need to support IE 8 & 9, it can work.

Comment: OK then @Michael_B you see how textarea works now in my example. If you achieve the same functionality, I will accept your answer!

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6me33s8y/3/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88849/discussion-between-gsamaras-and-michael-b).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS of the logo add the line:

Example: (Desktop)

```
#logo {
        .....
        vertical-align: middle; 
        .... 
      }
```

Example: (mobile)

```
@media (max-width:your width)
     {
     #logo { 
        width: your max width! or 100%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        ....
       }
     }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I created another div to contain the textarea

```
<div class="ui-block-solo">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Vanamo_Logo.png" id="logo">
</div>
<div class="ui-block-solo2">
    <textarea id="cagetextbox" placeholder='Talk to the Cage world!'>  </textarea>
</div>
```

and add the following css:

```
.ui-block-solo {
    float:left;
}

.ui-block-solo2 {
    float:right;
}
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6me33s8y/2/

---

**Update my own answer:**

Actually, you can just add float: left to the logo, and it will work without changing the html code

```
#logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 169px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Very good attempt Harry, nice! However, Michael threw in his solution first (in the comments, thus I am going to accept him). Thanks!

Comment: @gsamaras Not a problem, the question was unanswered when I wrote my answer. Glad you solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

The sort of layout you're seeking can be easily accomplished with **[CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)**.

Here's all the code you need:

```
.ui-block-solo {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 185px;
}

#logo {
    width: 200px;
    height: 169px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 2%;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .ui-block-solo { flex-direction: column; }
    #logo { position: static; }
}
```

*On larger screens:*

[image]

*On smaller screens:*

[image]

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/6me33s8y/7/

No changes to the HTML. No changes to JS/jQuery. A pure CSS solution.

*Note: Flexbox is supported by all major browsers [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).*

Comment: Michael you should update your username to Michael_G, because this is Great. However, I was not clear enough in the chat. I wanted the textbox to be placed in the center, not the logo. So I want the logo to be on the left, while the textbox lies on the center. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks for the compliment. What you're saying in your comment is exactly what I did. The textbox is in the center (on larger screens) and the logo is on the left (on larger screens)

Comment: Pleasure. Damn, in the fiddle what you say it's true, while in my project, it's not. Trying to figure it out! No Mike, what happens in the fiddle is what I want.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know anything about Aptana studio. I know the code in my answer works in the Chrome, FF, Safari, and IE>10, but I can't tell you about flexbox support from Aptana.

Comment: OK Mike I got this working. One last tuning and your answer will be ideal. Check what happens when there is no text in the textbox, which is going to be the default. The logo gets out of the border of the header! Can you change that, without altering the `height` of the logo?

Comment: I was preparing an alternative answer for you using traditional CSS properties, like `floats` and positioning. Do you not need that anymore?

Comment: Mike I can't see why. I mean what you have there is just perfect, except the thing I mentioned with the empty textbox, so I don't feel like I need an alternative answer (except if is solves the problem of the empty textbox). :) Will check tomorrow, if you can't fix it, let me know. ;)